# Apply a specific arima model to another time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have created an arima model with R based on time series x.

```
mod1 <- auto.arima(x)
```

Now I want to see how well this particular model fits a second time series y (maybe get R squared or p-value). I can't seem to find which command this is. I don't think it's "forecast", maybe just arima with different parameters (e.g. passing mod1?).

Thanks for the help!

update--

One thing I tried is the following:

```
refit <- Arima(y, model=mod1)
```

This now gives me (on a toy example):

```
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept
              4
s.e.          0

sigma^2 estimated as 2.4:  log likelihood=-9.28
AIC=20.57   AICc=21.9   BIC=20.18
```

I'm a bit confused on how to interpret these results. Is there a p-value indicating how well series y fits the model of series x or a similar value?

Comment: Would I be able to do something like predict.Arima(y, mod1), with y being the second time series?

Comment: What about refit <- Arima(y, model=mod1) and the accuracy(refit). Would that Do what I asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
refit <- Arima(y, model=mod1)
accuracy(refit)
```

This returns a bunch of measures such as MAPE and MASE to analyse how well one model can be used to predict the other data.